# The derivation of the quantum information no-hiding theorem, question 1

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am reading [Samuel L. Braunstein, Arun K. Pati, Quantum information cannot be completely hidden in correlations: implications for the black-hole information paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603046). I am puzzling over the derivation in Section Perfect hiding processes.

The authors have already assumed from the outset that only the ancilla $A$ and thus its orthornomal basis $A_k$'s depend on $\psi$. Does it not already imply their conclusion "any information about $|\psi\rangle$ that is encoded globally is in fact encoded entirely within the ancilla. No information about $|\psi\rangle$ is encoded in system-ancilla correlations (nor, in fact, in system-system correlations)."? There is a statement preceding it stating that "We may swap $|\psi\rangle$ with any other state in the ancilla using purely ancilla-local operations". But I do not see how and why this is necessary. Moreover, what would it be like to have "system-ancilla correlations"? Would it be for $|k\rangle$ to depend on $|\psi\rangle$?

---

***[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23745/55)***

Comment: Would the downvoter care to state his reason for downvoting this question?