# The derivation of the quantum information no-hiding theorem, question 2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am reading [Samuel L. Braunstein, Arun K. Pati, Quantum information cannot be completely hidden in correlations: implications for the black-hole information paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603046). The paper purportedly proves quantum information cannot be completely hidden in the ancilla. I am puzzling over the derivation in Section Perfect hiding processes. A closely related question is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689661/17354).

Does Equation $(3)$ of the paper
$$\alpha^*\beta\langle A_l(\psi)|A_k(\psi_\perp)\rangle+\beta^*\alpha\langle A_l(\psi_\perp)|A_k(\psi)\rangle=0 \tag3$$
come from the following requirements?
$$\big\langle A_l(\alpha|\psi\rangle+\beta|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big| A_k(\alpha|\psi\rangle+\beta|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big\rangle=0, \tag{3.1}$$
$$\big\langle A_l(|\psi\rangle)\big| A_k(|\psi\rangle)\big\rangle=\big\langle A_l(|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big| A_k(|\psi_\perp\rangle)\big\rangle=0. \tag{3.2}$$
If so, what is the rigorous rationale for Equations $(3.1), (3.2)$?